# How to convert cdf to stl format

Tags: export, graphics3d, conversion

I have the CDF version of the file that i need to 3D print, and because it wont let me convert to an STL format the normal way, how can i convert it.Is there a format i can convert it to, then open it in another software and 3D print from there?

Comment: Hard to say without any example code...

Comment: CDF is a format that includes executable Mathematica code, STL is a graphics format -- so you cannot straightforwardly convert from one to the other. Probably the thing to do is to draw the 3D object in the CDF and then export that object to the STL file.

Comment: I think the question is "how to export an object in a CFD to stl". @Faith maybe want to edit the title and explain if you only have the free viewer to work with.

Comment: Thank You , i will try that ,Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
SetDirectory @ $TemporaryDirectory;

CDFDeploy[
  "test.cdf"
, Manipulate[
    Column@List@Graphics3D[{ Cuboid[], Sphere[{2, 2, Dynamic[x]}]}]
  , {x, 0, 1}
  ]
];
```

You need to:

- extract content of `BoxData`.
- use `Setting` to convert all `Dynamic` to literal values.
- strip everything that wraps `Graphics3D`.

Maybe there is something more that I've missed but it is hard to say without examples.

```
Export[
  "my2.stl"
, Cases[
    Setting @ ToExpression @ Import["test.cdf"][[1, 1, 1, 1]]
  , _Graphics3D
  , \[Infinity]
  ]
, "STL"
]
```

[image]